# Filter rows in SLT

Tags: filter, slt

How to filter rows in SLT (SAP Landscape Transformation)

The filter should be based on one column of the table. And only if a cell in this row has a specific content then the row should be replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters can be defined in the transaction `LTRS`

Example

Filter rows if in column /BIC/R_GES is any value other than L

```
if i_/BIC/R_GES_1 <> 'L'. SKIP_RECORD. endif.
```

Note the prefix "i_" and the appendix "_1"

[image]